# Jquery Mobile: Full-width buttons like navbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Jquery mobile 1.4.2

I've been trying to use the navbar for providing menu buttons at the top of my jquery mobile page.

[image: Navigation Bar]

It looks like this and is intended to navigate between pages.  But I only really want it to activate some popups when clicked or run javascript to refresh the page.  It *looks* like I want it to look, but it acts like a nav bar.  Meaning, the buttons you click stay lit up, like you see in the "sort" button here.

I've googled and the only suggestion I've found is to edit the CSS so the buttons don't light up when active.  I could do this, but I think I may want to actually use the navbar as intended later in my project.

I updated to try to use grids, tables, controlgroups, etc. but can't achieve the same effect as the navbar provides.

Comment: I found if I use a grid and *buttons* I can achieve this.  But now I am working to figure out how to open pop ups from buttons.  If you change the button to an HREF with data-role="button" you lose the 100% fill.  It only 100% fills with *buttons*.

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="ui-grid-c">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><button onclick='$( "#sortmenu" ).popup( "open" )' data-corners="false" data-theme="f">Sort</button></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><button onclick='$( "#filtermenu" ).popup( "open" )' data-corners="false" data-theme="f">Filter</button></div>
            <div class="ui-block-c"><button onclick="$('#gallery_search_area').show();$('#gallery_page_content').hide();$('#gallery_page_summary').hide();" data-corners="false" data-theme="f">Search</button></div>
            <div class="ui-block-d"><button onclick="clearAllGalleryFilters();" data-corners="false" data-theme="f">Clear</button></div>
        </div>`

This is what I ultimately did.  It worked like I was hoping, but took a lot of trial an error.  Hopefully this will help someone else or maybe I'm just being thick :)  Either way... this is what worked.